# How to put "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header in a sling node

Tags: curl, aem, sling

I am facing a CORS ie. Same Origin Policy when I am trying to fetch the web service from the server. All I need to do is to put this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in my sling node. I have tried using the curl command to include the header but it didn't work. 
So, Please tell me a way so that I can put this header in my apache sling node and resolve this CORS issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is probably too broad. Why not just allow the domain you're attempting to make requests from?

Comment: Also, do you own the web service in question? Or are you trying to add the header to the request itself?

Comment: We own the Web Service and how could I allow the domain we are attempting to make request from?

Comment: Node is a unit of data in JCR repository (something like row in a relational database). It has nothing to do with http requests. Do you want include the header to the Sling HTTP responses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a filter and make sure that it hits for your website only.
(you can do that using filter.pattern osgi property)
and have the below doFilter method,

```
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
        String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
        if (origin != null) {
            if (origin.contains("yourwebsitename")) {
                 response.addHeader("Access-control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                 response.addHeader("Access-control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Thanks,
Balaji.